# My custom list view does not work

Tags: android, android-listview

i want to create a custom list view, but when i run the program it breaks with a exception:

**logcat:**
[image: logcat screen]

in **onCreate** method:

```
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    String items[] = {"cat", "dog", "horse", "monkey"};

    list.setAdapter(new myAdapter(items));
```

in **myAdapter** class:

```
private class myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private String items[];
    public myAdapter(String items[]) {
        super(ListViewExample.this, R.layout.row, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent);
        TextView label=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.row_textView1);
        label.setText(items[position]);
        return view;
    }

}
```

My main activity:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

</ListView>
```

And my template row:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can i fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: use converView instead of view and try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to set the third parameter (attachToRoot) to false while inflating the row.

Try this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
```

It would be even better to re-use the convertView if available:

```
View view = convertView;
if (convertView == null) {
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inflate your view like :

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent,false);
```

**AttachToRoot** (Third Argument): Whether the inflated hierarchy should be attached to the root parameter? If false, root is only used to create the correct subclass of LayoutParams for the root view in the XML

Answer (score 0):

inflate like this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
```